# Why does the Rust book present assigning a variable to another as copying the top-level structure?

Tags: rust, ownership-semantics

In the [section on ownership in *The Rust Programming Language*](https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/second-edition/ch04-01-what-is-ownership.html), `String`s are represented as a structure with 3 fields (with one of the 3 fields being a pointer to the actual byte vector). There is an example:

```
let s1 = String::from("hello");
let s2 = s1;
```

The book explains this as copying the 3-field structure contained in `s1` to `s2` (but not the byte-vector) and then marking the structure contained in `s1` as "invalid" (figure 4-4).

Why is it presented that way instead of presenting `s2` as pointing to the same top-level structure as `s1` and then marking `s1` as "invalid"?

Would this alternate presentation result in a visible difference in semantics (or would it even cause problems)?  If not, is it because it better reflects the underlying implementation?  And if so, why would the implementation make such a copy operation?

Answer (score 5):

> Why is it presented that way

Because that's a very close (if not exact) way of modeling Rust's ownership and moving semantics.

> Would this alternate presentation result in a visible difference in semantics

Yes. Rust's current semantics indicate that when a variable is moved, there's no guarantee that it remains at the same address. Your alternate presentation would suggest to readers that the address is *guaranteed* to be the same ("because the picture told me so!").

This cannot be the case for every move, so it's not worth teaching people misleading semantics. It's hard to pinpoint specifics, but cases I'd expect to have a *higher* chance of the value moving:

- Transferring them across threads
- Returning values from a function — although (Named) Return Value Optimization can prevent this.
- When the value is "very small" — it's cheaper to copy it than to dereference memory.

> why would the implementation make such a copy operation?

The **implementation** doesn't necessarily make a copy. While the **semantics** provide no guarantee that the address stays the same, they also don't enforce that it *must* change. In fact, the optimizer spends time attempting to minimize all sorts of needless copies where it can. The particular example in question is extremely likely to not involve any copies.

Comment: Do you have an example where pointer-equality cannot be preserved?